# int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter should be restart after a few minutes of work?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I use `Spring Integration` in my project,i have a `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter` in my context as below:

```
 <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="test-inbound-channel-adapter"
                                     channel="tmp-channel"
                                     session-factory="ftp-Session"
                                     auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                     delete-remote-files="true"
                                     auto-startup="${ftp.active}"
                                     filename-regex="my regex ...."
                                     remote-directory="${ftp.input.path}"
                                     remote-file-separator="/"
                                     local-filename-generator-expression="@fileNameGenerator.generateNameBy('test',#this)"
                                     temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
                                     local-directory="${backupRootPath}/test/tmp//">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

it's work correctly,but does not work with ftp server after a few minutes of work and system should be restart,error log as below:

```
2016-07-31 17:11:08.381 ERROR 2980 --- [sk-scheduler-10] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:266)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:193)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:295)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:223)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:410)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:223)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:483)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:821)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1854)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.read(FtpSession.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:288)
    ... 26 more
```

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That does not make sense. Share, please, more symptoms like stack traces, logs, maybe even something to play from our side locally... Or that might be some your FTP server restrictions and some options should be switched on for your client in its policies

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for reply me,the post has been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to customize your `DefaultFtpSessionFactory`. For example client mode:

```
/**
 * ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE = 0 <br>
 * A constant indicating the FTP session is expecting all transfers
 * to occur between the client (local) and server and that the server
 * should connect to the client's data port to initiate a data transfer.
 * This is the default data connection mode when and FTPClient instance
 * is created.
 * PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE = 2 <br>
 * A constant indicating the FTP session is expecting all transfers
 * to occur between the client (local) and server and that the server
 * is in passive mode, requiring the client to connect to the
 * server's data port to initiate a transfer.
 *
 * @param clientMode The client mode.
 */
public void setClientMode(int clientMode) {
```

There are other options about timeouts:

```
/**
 * Set the connect timeout for the socket.
 * @param connectTimeout the timeout
 */
public void setConnectTimeout(int connectTimeout) {
     this.connectTimeout = connectTimeout;
}

/**
 * Set the (socket option) timeout on the command socket.
 * @param defaultTimeout the timeout.
 */
public void setDefaultTimeout(int defaultTimeout) {
    this.defaultTimeout = defaultTimeout;
}

/**
 * Set the (socket option) timeout on the data connection.
 * @param dataTimeout the timeout.
 */
public void setDataTimeout(int dataTimeout) {
    this.dataTimeout = dataTimeout;
}
```

Of course that would be much better to consult with your FTP server to determine why it doesn't like your connections and drops them.

Comment: Please, let us know what was the problem really

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for support me, i see `vsftp` log on ftp server ,when i send command via `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter` create the new connection with server and after several minutes,server connections Is too much, it may be cause my problem?